# Python - Simple Question: Numpy Matrix, Loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, numpy, matrix

I am fairly new to python and I am trying to get around understanding the following code:

```
import numpy as np
n=4
matrix=np.zeros((n,n))
for j in range (0,n):
    for i in range (n-1,n-j-2,-1):
        matrix[i,j]=2*n-i-j-1
print (matrix)
```

I would greatly appreciate if someone could please help me understand how each line executes and how the code is revaluated with the loop.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In short: It creates a 4 by 4 array where each cell in the lower left triangle has the value `i - j + 1` where `i` is the row index and `j` is the column index. You need to be more specific about what you don't understand if that does not solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply! My question is how do I know that the lower left triangle is the one where the matrix formula executes. Sorry if it is way too obvious, but I am a complete begginner

Comment: The outer `for` loop iterates over the row indices. The inner `for` loop iterates over the columns, but only up to the column number that is equal to the current row number.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following print statement, and the loop will explain itself at each iteration:

```
n=4
matrix=np.zeros((n,n))
for i in range (0,n):
    for j in range(0,i+1):
        print(f'inserting {i-j+1} into the matrix at row index {i}, columns index {j}')
        matrix[i,j]=i-j+1
```

When you run it, you get this output:

```
inserting 1 into the matrix at row index 0, columns index 0
inserting 2 into the matrix at row index 1, columns index 0
inserting 1 into the matrix at row index 1, columns index 1
...
inserting 3 into the matrix at row index 3, columns index 1
inserting 2 into the matrix at row index 3, columns index 2
inserting 1 into the matrix at row index 3, columns index 3
```

And your matrix is populated as before:

```
>>> matrix
array([[1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [2., 1., 0., 0.],
       [3., 2., 1., 0.],
       [4., 3., 2., 1.]])
```

Just for reference:

```
>>> matrix
array([[1., 0., 0., 0.],   #<- "row" index 0
       [2., 1., 0., 0.],   #<- "row" index 1
       [3., 2., 1., 0.],   #<- "row" index 2
       [4., 3., 2., 1.]])  #<- "row" index 3

      # ^      ...  ^
      # "col" 0     "col" 3
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was really helpful!!

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
n=4
```

We start by setting a 4x4 matrix with all coordinates set to null:

```
matrix=np.zeros((n,n))
```

We set new coordinate values by looping through rows and columns. First we loop through rows, from index 0 to n-1:

```
for i in range (0,n):
```

We next loop through columns. Now, notice that we only loop through those columns whose index is smaller than or equal to that of the current row (i.e., from 0 to i). This way we make sure that the values we set are on or below the diagonal of the matrix:

```
    for j in range(0,i+1):
```

Finally, we set the desired value for the current coordinate:

```
        matrix[i,j]=i-j+1
print(matrix)
```